# Should I create a model to contain another model instances? (Django)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to django so I'm not sure of the proper way to do things *(or the convention)*.

Say I want to make a project which contains my everyday notes.

I'm going to create multiple notes every day *(where each note is going to be an instance of a "Note" model)*.

I want in my project-frontend to have containers, where I start with containers, each of a specific year *(say 2020, 2021, ...)* and each of these containers contains month containers *(Jan, Feb, ...)* and each of those contains day containers *(1, 2, ..)* and each of those contains the notes of this specific day.
[image]

Now my question is should, in my backend, make a NoteYear model which has instances of a NoteMonth model which has instances of NoteDay model which has instances of Note model?
[image]

I understand that I can filter the objects by the DateTimeField, and put them in different containers in the frontend *(Of course I'll have a DateTimeField for each Note instance anyways)*.

The reason I thought of this is because it should be faster filtering to get to a specific day.

I'd love to hear your opinions!

Comment: No, never write models in based on what should happen in the frontend. Models should focus on representing and storing data as effective as possible.

Comment: So you believe I should note created nested models for the Dates and just filtering them in the code, even though it would be less time-efficient?

Comment: it makes not much sense to make "*pure fabrication*" models just to determine the year, month day. If you make a database index (`db_index=True`) on the datetime, it will do the lookup in efficient time.

Comment: I just searched this and it sounds like the perfect solution. If you can link an example so I can understand how to use it exactly, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models should *not* be written based on how to present data at the front-end. Models should try to represent and store data in an effective manner.

Here it would be *pure fabrication* to create models for the year, month and day items. A simple `Note` model with a `DateTimeField` should suffice, especially if you add a database index to that field such that it can easily filter.

Such model thus looks like:

```
from django.db import models

class Note(models.Model):
    note = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

You can then effectively retrieve items for a given year, month, day with:

```
Note.objects.filter(created__year=2021)  # year
Note.objects.filter(created__year=2021, created__month=9)  # month
Note.objects.filter(created__year=2021, created__month=9, day=25)  # day
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use models as storage objects which means you don't have to define your models based on each and every container.

Accordingly, you may define you `models` as follows and use `django-template` to iterate and filter by dates into years/months/days.

```
class Notes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
```